# What is a less vulgar way of referring to someone's posterior?

Tags: word-choice, colloquial-language

What is the least vulgar but still natural (not overly formal) of these: Bum, bottom, backside, behind, rear end...

As she walked past him, he stared at her _________.

Comment: This is a highly subjective question hence my addition of the "colloquial" tag. The degree of vulgarity is specific to each persons ethics. A native of England might use bum, someone from Seattle in the USA might use backside. And even the  vulgar forms might seem acceptable to some people. I was raised to never swear, so A$$ is considered vulgar, as is the formal "buttocks".

Comment: @GWarner Buttocks is considered vulgar? That's crazy. It's the [proper anatomical / medical term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buttocks).

Comment: @TypeIA I know. I said vulgarity can be subjective. As a child I learned to not contradict grandparents skewed ethics and decorum.

Answer (score 1):

"Bum" A little bit naughty.  Naughty enough to make five-year-olds giggle with the rudeness.

"bottom" Fairly standard. Common, but not vulgar.

"backside"/"behind"/"rear end" are all euphemisms.  All equally polite.

The last three are the least vulgar, but none are rude enough to cause offence.

Comment: Could she not have said "boil on their bum" or "boil on their behind" (and still preserve the alliteration)  "Bum" is perhaps slightly naughty, but no more.